# Add Fade effect to angular2 ng-bootstrap tabs

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

can anyone help me to add fading effect on ng-bootstrap tabs.
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabs

Comment: Hello, Please mention what have you tried so far to get fading effect. And put some of your code that illustrate where exactly you want the effect and how. Have you tried bootstrap Tabs with fade-in fade-out effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you asking for something like this ? :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'your_component',
  animations: [
    trigger('fadeInOutTranslate', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({opacity:0}),
        animate(300, style({opacity:1}))
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [
        style({transform: 'translate(0)'}),
        animate(300, style({opacity:0}))
      ])
    ])
  ],
  template: '<div [@fadeInOutTranslate] class="container"></div>',
})
```

don't forget to add  `import { transition, animate } from '@angular/core';`

in case : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html

Answer (score 2):

Try This

in your app.component.ts file

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger("animationFedInFedOut", [
        transition("* => fadeIn", [
            style({ opacity: 0 }),
            animate(300, style({ opacity: 1 }))
        ]),
        transition("* => fadeOut", [
            animate(300, style({ opacity: 0 }))
        ])
    ])
]
})

export class AppComponent {
bindingVar = "";
fadeIn() {
    this.bindingVar = "fadeIn";
}

fadeOut() {
    this.bindingVar = "fadeOut";
}

fedEffect() {
    this.bindingVar == "fadeOut" ? this.fadeIn() : this.fadeOut();
}

hide() {
    this.fadeOut();
}
}
```

html code: in your app.component.html file

```
<tabset>
   <tab (select)="fedEffect()" class="active" heading="Tab 1"> 
    <div [@animationFedInFedOut]="bindingVar" >  tab Content 1</div>
   </tab>
   <tab (select)="fedEffect()" heading="Tab 2" >
    <div [@animationFedInFedOut]="bindingVar" >  tab Content 2</div>
   </tab>
</tabset>
```

Comment: We have to use (selectTab) instead of (select)